# Xdebug not working with PDT "waiting for Xdebug Session"

Tags: php, apache, xdebug, netstat

I am trying to configure Xdebug with Eclipse PDT plugin. I have gone through lots of tutorial in web and also went through stackoverflow.com existing question. But didn't find the answer to this:
i am using Eclipse 3.7 with the latest PDT plugin. Have done correct debug configuration in eclipse. Also i have changed the listening port of Eclipse xdebug to 9009. I have also given the same number to

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9009
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=10
xdebug.var_display_max_data=10240
xdebug.auto_trace=1
xdebug.trace_output_dir=/tmp
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so
```

at the end when i run

```
netstat -anp --tcp --udp | grep LISTEN
```

i get the following output

```
tcp6       0      0 :::10000                :::*                    LISTEN      2949/eclipse    
tcp6       0      0 :::9009                 :::*                    LISTEN      2949/eclipse
```

i see eclipse in the list but not the apache or xdebug.

and my session to the Xdebug in eclipse is hangs saying "Waiting for Xdebug Session"...

anybody have idea how to debug this further

Comment: found the problem here.. there was a problem (syntax error ) in my php.ini file. so it was never parsed completely. fix the error its working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been through this... 
I spent hours like you reading the same message... I learned a lot, but nothing worked.
Does your Internet connection use a router? If this is true then you could have my problem.
Just try to port forward port 9000. I don't know a lot about this ports and routers stuff... so I'll give you a pic of my router config.

[image]

I really hope that helps.